# How to access a particular leaf using the Composite Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

If I wanted to access the seven hundredth and seventy seventh leaf of a Composite node, and only access that leaf, is that possible with the Composite Pattern, or is that type of access outside the domain of the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the [Composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). The general version of that pattern does not let you skip directly to leaves, so you'll have to walk the children recursively. In pseudocode:

```
stack = []
stack.push(rootElement)
results = []

while(stack is not empty) {
  elt = stack.pop()
  if (elt.is_leaf()) {
    results.push(elt)
  }
  else { // not a leaf: add children to the stack
    for (c in elt.children()) {
      stack.push(c)
    }
  }
}
```

At that point, you can access the 77th element of `results` to get the 77th leaf, as measured in 'children you found out about first' order. Keep in mind that, in general, just saying 'the 77th leaf' is not very meaningful unless you give a precise account of what your ordering criterion is.

Comment: @cs student: I'd need a lot more detail to answer that in a meaningful way. Perhaps you could elaborate a bit in the original question (hit `edit`)?

Comment: @cs student: Nothing jumps to mind based on your code. Maybe a high-level answer to your reorg question: if you have a lot of objects to 'model' keep track of, and you want the 'view' objects to stay in sync, then you can a couple of things. One is to do publisher/subscriber (a design pattern). This works well if the mapping from model to view objects is not always 1 to 1, since you can make multiple view objects listen to the same model object. If the mapping *is* 1 to 1, then there is no reason not to just `extend` the Swing classes and implement 'view' and 'model' behavior in place.